# Why can't I render any Quarto documents into pdfs?

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto, miktex

I am able to render Quarto documents into html just fine, but whenever I try pdfs I get this error:

`compilation failed- no matching packages LaTeX Error: File` scrartcl.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.10 ^^M`

This problem arose when I updated R, but I need to update R so my other packages work. This also happens on both my computer and my laptop, which have completely different versions of R.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the entirety of R and RStudio. I also looked up this issue, saw it was recommended to look at MikTeX's console for updates, and downloaded that to check, but it's fully updated and does not show me any issues. I also have tried downloading the missing packages myself like texlive-latex-recommended but when I do that I get this error:

`Warning in install.packages : package ‘texlive-latex-recommended’ is not available for this version of R`

I get this same error for koma-script (which was also recommended to be installed) and MikTeX itself. MikTeX console tells me it's on its latest version; and I didn't even have the console until I started getting this error so it was still happening even on an older version. I don't know how to fix this anymore.

Comment: Could you please try `install.packages("tinytex")`?

Comment: @Quinten I installed that and it worked, but I still get the error and can’t install any tex related packages outside of that.

Comment: I have been running into this problem as well. It happened to me when I used gt to create the table and I tried to use the tab_stub_indent function to indent the rows. I then tried kable with the pack_rows function and received a different error (LaTeX Error: File 'tabu.sty' not found.) Everything renders find to HTML. Trying a different way altogether for the time being.